# Animation navigation in Deck.js

Tags: deck.js

On Deck.js pages with animations I would like to have a visul indicator for the transitions so I know how many a deck has.  Similar to deck.status, but for a given slide not the deck.  We are using Deck.js for several two day classes and its difficult to recall the transitions left on a page when stepping through an animation.

For example, the deck at [SVG demo](http://home.heeere.com/data/deck-js-demo-2/samples/deck-svg.html#slide-13) has 8 transitions or steps.  There is no visual indicator knowing that the 7th arrow press will stay on the slide, but the 8th will jump to the next slide.

Looking for something like Android's DotsPageIndicator or Harvey Balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had partly the same need: knowing when the last subslides are displayed. As a presenter, we need to know that but also the audience should now so they can take a picture at the right moment.

I just commited the code to the step extension (and the packed versions):

https://github.com/twitwi/deck.js/commit/efe9e862cd2c7ea8253ab7570856e90fe10f60d2

https://github.com/twitwi/deck.js/commit/8ce4d667dcdfeaceb8775d08d810584cddddb082

There is an example that adds an icon on each last sub slide here:

https://github.com/twitwi/deck.js-starterkit

https://twitwi.github.io/deck.js-starterkit/

It is not a full subslide counter but it might already be useful.